# Plain Terrain in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, terrain

I am trying to draw a plane terrain in using ThreeJS but it doesn't work.

Here is my plane creation code:

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 300), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff
    }));
plane.overdraw = true;
this.scene.add(plane);
```

Pretty straight-forward. Actually I just copied it from some site.

This is how I initialize scene and camera:

```
    this.camera =
        new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        45, // view angle
        width / height, // aspect
        0.1, // near
        10000); // far

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // add the camera to the scene
    this.scene.add(this.camera);

    // the camera starts at 0,0,0
    // so pull it back
    this.camera.position.z = 800;
    this.camera.position.y = -100;
```

I also have a sphere of radius 20 in the center. It shows up just fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera is looking at the "back face" of the plane.

A plane have two sides, but only one is visible.

Two solutions:

**1)** Move the camera to look at the "front face" of the plane:

```
this.camera.position.y = 100;
```

**2)** Or, activate the `doubleSided` flag:

```
plane.doubleSided = true;
```

Comment: Thank you. Something useful to know ;)